# Does the Trueshot Aura ( Pristress of the Moon) effect huntress?

Tags: warcraft-3, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

The ability `Trueshot Aura` of the Hero `Pristress of the Moon` from the Night elves gives bonus damage to ranged units. Officially huntress are considered Melee units. However I have seen the combination hunter + Pristress w. Aura. I have also read, that this is considered a strong combo.

I therefore wonder, whether huntress gain positive affect by the trueshot aura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Trueshot Aura gives bonus damage to huntress', as seen on this picture [image: Image of Huntress + Trueshot Aura]

It also says so on the Warcraft 3 battle.net http://classic.battle.net/war3/nightelf/units/huntress.shtml